Lan with wired and wifi PCs used to work, now only the wi fi ones work and wired can't even ping each other
I have a weird problem that's been driving me crazy for some weeks.
The basics:
I have four PCs in my home LAN. The four of them are on the same workgroup, homegroup is disabled, I use the "old style" networking. I have users with same name and password on all the computers, the shared folders have the permissions and security settings properly configured to allow the users to access, and everything worked until some weeks ago.
The four computers had internet, sharing folders and printers, remote desktop or VNC, even games ran fine in local multiplayer lan mode. (Like Quake 2 using TCP IP or DOOM using some IPX WRAPPER).
I get internet by fiber optics, the ISP came to my home and installed the fiber optics cable and a router. (ZTE 660).
I plug the LAN cables to that router, and it has wi fi too. The problem is some weeks ago the wired computers "disappeared" from the lan. The wi fi computers still work perfectly, they have all, shared folders, internet, remote desktop, they can ping each other, but the wired computers only have internet. They can't even ping each other!.
They can ping the router, they can ping a web site, but the wired computers are invisible to each other AND to the wi fi computers.
The computers are:

PC1 - Win 10 - wired to the router. dhcp, 192.168.1.2 (LAN1 port).
PC2 - Win 7 - wi fi. dhcp, 192.168.1.41.
PC3 - XP SP3 - wi fi* (ethernet wired to repeater. dhcp disabled) 192.168.1.5.
PC4 - 98SE - wired to the router. dhcp, 192.168.1.31 (LAN4 port).

IPv6 is disabled everywhere: in the router settings, in the network card properties it's unchecked, and I disabled the IPHELPER service. I'm running only IPv4.
Checking with ipconfig and looking at the network card properties everything is fine, all the PCs have the same gateway 192.168.1.1, the same subnet mask 255.255.255.0, etc.
Both the Windows 7 and Windows 10 PCs have the same settings in the "network and sharing settings":
private/home profile, turned on network discovery and file and printer sharing, password protected is off, 128 bit is off. All the requiered services are enabled (like function discovery and publishing, ssdp discovery, netbios over tcp ip, server, workstation, computer browser, upnp, those things).
One day it stopped working. I didn't change anything, nothing auto updated, it's not a virus, I didn't install anything new, suddenly only the computers on wi fi can see each other. Internet still works fine on all of the computers.
I tried all the possible troubleshooting like reseting winsock, uninstalling all the network card drivers and leaving only the basic windows drivers, reinstalling the proper network card driver, leaving everything off and unplugged for a couple of hours, replacing all the LAN cables, disabling all firewalls, disabling windows defender, testing the different possible configurations of the computer browser service in the registry, I mean the "keep list" yes, no, auto. Testing the LMmcompatibility registry key set to 1 or 3 (it's usually 1 on win 10, 7 and XP, 3 on 98, that's how you get 98 to use ntlm and see the more modern OSes).
I tried renaming the workgroup just in case, I tried putting all of the computers on fixed IP, I FORMATTED AND DID FRESH INSTALLS, but I got the same results.
In the router the isolation thing is disabled, so the wi fi part should be able to communicate with the wired part.
Oh, if I wire any of the wi fi computers, they disappear from the network, BUT... if I plug the wired PCs to wi fi with a repeater, they work fine again.
Sorry for the long post I tried to be as specific and helpful as I could to not waste people's time.
Any help will be appreciated.

Sounds like some kind of "network isolation" setting in the router.

I checked the router settings and isolation is disabled, it's a zte 660, the specific setting is in "network, wlan, basic, enable isolation" and it's unchecked.
something called "sgi enable" is unchecked too, I don't know what that is.
"qos type" says wmm, I don't know what that is either.
on SSID settings there's "hide SSID", it's disabled, and "SSID isolation", it's disabled too.
maybe I should take screenshots of all the settings?.

Ok, I just disabled WLAN, let's forget about wi fi for a moment, I wired two computers, the most new ones, let's forget about XP and 98 too. Let's make this simple.
**Router: ZTE 660.
**PC1 - WIN10 - 192.168.1.2.
**PC2 - WIN7 - 192.168.1.11.
dhcp is enabled.
no firewall, nothing in the router settings is blocking anything (like some ip filter or whatever).
the router can ping both computeres.
both computers can ping the router at 192.168.1.1.
both computers have internet but they can't even ping each ohter.

Are you sure the computers are not blocking ICMP/whatever ping protocol Windows is using?  What happens if you pit the PC's on the same switch and connect the switch to a LAN port on the router? (That could tell us if the problem relates to the switch emulation on the router)

I made sure in the advanced firewall properties the icmp protocols are allowed for domain, public and private, but I tested with firewall disabled anyway.
on the router settings I didn't saw anything blocking any protocols, specific IPs or mac adresses. The zte 660 router is the only device. the ISP fiber optics cable comes in, and it has 4 lan ports as output.
I tested all combinations like "port 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4, 1 and 3, 1 and 4..." and the PCs can't ping each other but they can ping the router 192.168.1.1, and the router's diagnostic page can see and ping all the PCs.

Heres the thing though - if we pretend for a moment that the 4 lan ports on the ZTE660 LTE are acting as a switch, the packets are not processed by the router (ie firewalling is not processed).  In reality, most of these embedded routers are emulating a switch by bridging the interfaces together, rather then being an actual switch - but that takes place at a fairly low level.  Replacing (even temporarily) the lan ports on the router with a switch will tell you if this is an issue with the IP stack on the PC's (which I think is more likely), or a quirk in the router.

Another trick to help narrow things down - after pinging each computer from the other, does the ARP table in each computer show the others MAC address?

1)About the IP stack, I did the reset winsock and flush dns thing:
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
ipconfig /flushdns
arp -d *
I don't think that's the problem.


I guess I should get a switch, plug the computers to it with ethernet cables and it to the ZTE 660 router.


I had found a solution, it worked for a day but now it's not working again. It's long so I'll make a big post down there. I suspect the ISP changed some rule, policy, protocol or something on their side.



to answer the ARP table question, after ping I did "arp -a". (I removed addresses for security or privacy).
Interface: 192.168.1.41 --- 0xb
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
192.168.1.1           blah             dynamic
192.168.1.5           blah            dynamic
224.0.0.22            blah            static
224.0.0.252           blah           static
239.255.255.250     blah          static
255.255.255.255     blah        static
.1 is the router
.41 uses wi fi directly.
.5 is plugged to a repeater.
I don't know what the other things are

No point in hiding that information, and what you have written above is pretty unintelligible as a result but each line in an ARP table should include the devices IP and a unique mac address (ie something in the form xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) - If (after attempting to ping between them) each computer has the other computers wired MAC address it says they are able to see each other directly, and the problem is not with the router.      A MAC address is a globally unique identifier for each ethernet or WIFI interface on your devices.

in the ARP table I see the ip and mac addess only of the wi fi computers and the router, not the wired ones.
I guess I won't know until I buy a switch as a middle step between the ISP's "device that gets the internet" and the computers. What's driving me crazy is it worked perfectly for years, and now it worked for a day when I factory resetted it and used the default SSID name and password, but now wired is back to be invisible.
Maybe they changed the service and allow only wi fi?. It's like they noticed "this guy found a work around!" and blocked it again.
Nothign of this makes sense.

I found a temporary solution, it worked for a day but now it's broken again.
I took screenshots of all the settings on the router just in case, and I resetted it to factory defaults. After rebooting, the wired PCs appeared on the LAN!. Everything worked!. (shared folders, remote desktop, ping), wired was normal again. The only difference between previous configuration and factory defaults was the SSID wifi name and password resetted to the ISP defaults, like "isp_nnn".That shouldn't have anything to do with the wired side.
I tried changing to what I use normally, wired LAN stopped working.
I tried changing only the password, it stopped working.
I tried changing the name to something new, it stopped working.
So... for THE WIRED side to work, THE WI FI side MUST have the ISP default name and password?????.
I said "no big deal, I'll change the phone and tablet to log in to that SSID".
So, the four computers were back on the lan (2 wired, 2 wi fi), everything worked great again but ONLY if I kept the router on factory default settings with the ISP's default wi fi name and password. It makes no sense, I've been using my own wi fi name and password for like 5 years now and they put it themselves, when the ISP technicians came to install fiber optics they asked "what wi fi name do you want?". it's not like I changed it recently or it wasn't allowed. It was always part of the service to have the wi fi name and password I wanted.
Well, I thought it was solved, but a day later I woke up to find out that the wired side of the LAN was invisible again.
They noticed I found a workaround and blocked it again?.
I'll buy a switch or secondary router as soon as I can to do more tests.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
